# How to map array with array objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array 1:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

And array 2:

```
[{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 5 }]
```

How to combine 2 arrays as below:

```
[{a: 1, b: 2: c: 3}]
```

The result only includes the items in first array.
I want an optimal solution.

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Thanks!
I will learn from experience for next time

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `reduce`

```js
a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'];
a2 = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 4, d: 5 }];

a = a1.reduce((a,key) => [... a, {[key]: a2[0][key]}], []);


console.log(a);
```

In case a key from the first array is missing in the second array, its value will be set as undefined.